# using String.Split in a LINQ Where clause not working

Tags: c#, linq, visual-studio-2013

I have below LINQ query:

```
List<string> paths = (from an in modelDb.MyTable
                            where an.Id == 0 &&
                                  an.fileName.Split('_')[0] == "19292929383833abe838ac393" &&
                                  an.fileName.Split('_')[1].ToUpper() == "FINANCE" &&
                                  an.fileName.ToUpper().Contains("SIGNED")
                            select an.filePath).ToList();
```

... which is throwing below error on run-time:

```
Entity Framework 'ArrayIndex' is not supported in LINQ to Entities
```

fileName field in the LINQ query is a column in MyTable of string data type and contains strings like:

```
8845abd344ejk3444_FINANCE_SIGNED.pdf
4565abd34ryjk3454_FINANCE_UNSIGNED.pdf
477474jkedf34dfe4_MARKETING_UNSIGNED.pdf
```

and so on...

Comment: Try to evaluate your query into in-memory collection and apply your `Where` clause. Your error tells that linq provider doesn't support your query

Comment: Fetch the data from the database and then apply your filtering logic on the in-memory collection. Or write a raw SQL query yourself to filter the data in the database.

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski is correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stays in the message split will be not supported in the linq to sql and if you want to get result without additional methods, using Contains() should give you required result

```
List<string> paths = (from an in modelDb.MyTable
        where an.Id == 0 &&
                an.fileName.Contains("19292929383833abe838ac393") &&
                an.fileName.Contains("FINANCE") &&
                an.fileName.ToUpper().Contains("SIGNED")
        select an.filePath).ToList();
```

Another way is to load all in memory and do split after that, e.g.

```
List<string> temp = (from an in modelDb.MyTable
                            where an.Id == 0  
                                  an.fileName.ToUpper().Contains("SIGNED")
                            select an.filePath).ToList();

paths = temp.Where(an =>
     an.fileName.Split('_')[0] == "19292929383833abe838ac393" &&
     an.fileName.Split('_')[1].ToUpper() == "FINANCE").ToList();
```